# MSChart Winforms. How to remove blank points?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I use the MSChart control for creating candlestick chart (namespace System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting). I added two points in friday and two points in monday. Total four points.

In result, I see four candlesticks and many blank points therebetween. How to remove it?

Thanks.

```
var area = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("area1");                
area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm";

var series = new Series("prices", 4);

series.ChartArea = "area1";
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;
series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
series["OpenCloseStyle"] = "Triangle";
series["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";
series["PointWidth"] = "0.6";
series["PriceUpColor"] = "Green";
series["PriceDownColor"] = "Red";

series.Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2016, 4, 25, 12, 0, 0), 2, 0.5, 0.7, 1.8);
series.Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2016, 4, 25, 11, 0, 0), 2, 0.5, 0.7, 1.8);
series.Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2016, 4, 22, 12, 0, 0), 2, 0.5, 0.7, 1.8);
series.Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2016, 4, 22, 11, 0, 0), 2, 0.5, 0.7, 1.8);                

this.chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

[image]

Comment: the X-Axis is a linear time-Axis, so what do you expect to see during the weekend? You want only to see working days?

Comment: Yes, I want to see only working days.

Comment: There are no "blank points". What you see are only the axis labels and chart grid lines for that period of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by telling the `Chart`, or rather the `Series`, that you want to use the `X-Values` as such (i.e. as numbers) but **not** for **placing** the `DataPoints`.

Here is what you have to add:

```
  series.IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

This means that you can still **format** them or **use** them in other ways like calculations but the **placement** is strictly **lined up** as if their values were indices 0,1,2... or as if you had added them as strings, leading to the x-values actually all be 0, as so many newbies do.

Now your chart looks like this (here):

[image]

**As has been noted** the gap you saw was not caused by **empty points**. To create an `Empty DataPoint` you would do something like this:

```
series.Points[2].IsEmpty = true;
```

And tell the series how to treat them:

```
series.EmptyPointStyle.Color = Color.Transparent;
series.EmptyPointStyle.AxisLabel = " ";
```

**Note** The DataPoints you added were **not ordered** by date. Therefore they **now** appear unordered. The best way to fix it is to order them before you add them.

If you can't do that you can sort them like this:

```
var sorted = series.Points.OrderBy(x => x.XValue).ToList();  // a sorted copy
series.Points.Clear();
foreach (DataPoint dp in sorted) series.Points.Add(dp);
```

[image]

Ordered with one `Empty` Point

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me.